# Unexecuted javascript code stop the execution another java script code in a html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am completely new to Javascript and web development. When I was programming a web page, I created two Javascript codes

```
     <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
     <script src="./js/ABuilder.js"></script>
     <script src="./js/BBuilder.js"></script>
     <script>
    $(document).ready()
    {

    initA();//a function from A

    }
    </script>
```

When I opened the web page, I checked on the debugger, function initA didn't execute. When I deleted.

```
<script src="./js/BBuilder.js"></script>
```

initA ran as I expected. But how could Bbuilder influence Abuilder since I haven't initialized the Bbuilder

the detail code about Bbuilder

```
var day;
var month;
function initB() {
var dataFile = "./js/b.json";
loadData(dataFile, loadB);
}

function loadData(jsonFile, callback) {

$.getJSON(jsonFile, function(json) {
    callback(json);
});
}
function loadB(data) {
day = data.day;
month = data.month;
}
```

Abuild Code

```
var age;
var gender;
function initA() {
var dataFile = "./js/a.json";
loadData(dataFile);
}


function loadData(jsonFile) {
 $.getJSON(jsonFile, function (json)  {

  loadA();
  });
}
function loadA(data) {
  age = data.age;
  gender = data.gender;
}`
```

Comment: The usage of `.ready()` is incorrect. Please make it as  `$(document).ready(function(){ initA(); })`

Comment: What do you mean by "function initA didn't execute"? If the `.ready()` bug above is fixed, `initA` should be executed. However, as `loadData()` is overridden by BBuilder.js, function `loadA()` won't be executed.

Comment: @shaochuancs If understand you correctly, the main reason my program doesn't work is because each time I introduce a new js file, the old method loadData() is overridden. Can I fix it my change the name of loadData() method? Btw, i am a beginner for js, so how I defined a polymorphism relation between two js files?

Comment: What do you mean by `polymorphism`? Do you want BBuilder extend from ABuilder?

Comment: @shaochuancs Do you mean I override the `getJson()` method in jquery,  otherwise how could BBuilder override a method in ABuilder?

Comment: I think I understand your question now. I'll provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

To wrap `ABuilder` and `BBuilder` and prevent variable conflict, you can put them into 2 classes. In this way, polymorphism relationship between these two js files can be defined.

Please check the following code snippet. In this example, class `ABuilder` and class `BBuilder` are defined. Then `BBuilder` is defined to extend from `ABuilder`, but override `loadData()` method.

```js
// ./js/jquery.js

// ./js/ABuilder.js
function ABuilder() {
  this.age = null;
  this.gender = null;
}
ABuilder.prototype = {
  initA: function() {
    var dataFile = "./js/a.json";
    this.loadData(dataFile);
  },
  loadData: function(jsonFile) {
    $.getJSON(jsonFile, function(json){
      this.loadA();
    }.bind(this));
  },
  loadA: function(data) {
    this.age = data.age;
    this.gender = data.gender;
  }
};

// ./js/BBuilder.js
function BBuilder() {
  this.day = null;
  this.month = null;
}
let aBuilderObj = new ABuilder();
aBuilderObj.initB = function() {
  var dataFile = "./js/b.json";
  this.loadData(dataFile, this.loadB);
};
aBuilderObj.loadData = function(jsonFile, callback) {
  $.getJSON(jsonFile, function(json) {
    callback(json);
  });
};
aBuilderObj.loadB = function(data) {
  this.day = data.day;
  this.month = data.month;
};
BBuilder.prototype = aBuilderObj;

// init script
$(document).ready(function() {
  let initedABuilder = new ABuilder();
  initedABuilder.initA();
});
```